# Retrive Table names from sqlite database in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

How can I retrieve sqlite3 table names in objective-c.For example if I created several tables, now i want to get (display) their names like `.table` in terminal.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)fetchTableNames
{   
    sqlite3_stmt* statement;
    NSString *query = @"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\'table\'";
    int retVal = sqlite3_prepare_v2(YOUR_DB_OBJ, 
                                    [query UTF8String],
                                    -1,
                                    &statement,
                                    NULL);

    NSMutableArray *selectedRecords = [NSMutableArray array];
    if ( retVal == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
        {
            NSString *value = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [selectedRecords addObject:value];
        }       
    }   

    sqlite3_clear_bindings(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    return selectedRecords;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

Comment: Tnx Peko, as I understand it this is my query but how do i get the name, to work with it, maybe you can add some more code

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where type='table'
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSArray *)listOfColumnNamesForTable:(NSString *)tableName WithDBFilePath:(NSString*)databasePath {

sqlite3 *sqlite3Database;
NSMutableArray *columnNames = [NSMutableArray array];
int openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3Database);
if(openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pragma table_info ('%@')",tableName];
    int prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database, [query UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
    if(prepareStatementResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_stmt* statement;
        int retVal = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database,
                                        [query UTF8String],
                                        -1,
                                        &statement,
                                        NULL);

        if ( retVal == SQLITE_OK )
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
            {
                NSString *value = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [columnNames addObject:value];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_clear_bindings(statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(sqlite3Database);
        return [columnNames mutableCopy];
    }



}
sqlite3_close(sqlite3Database);
return nil;
```

}